# Debugging typescript app with console input at runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

am trying to learn typescript and looking for some help with setting up debugger support in VS code. Here is my sample TS app which is a standalone app just prints "Hello World" text in console on data entered in console. How do i provide console input after the application is launched?  I place a break point in console.log at line 6, the execution stops there when launched. But I want  to enter runtime console input and inspect the console.log at line 4.

Index.ts:

```
class Startup {
    public static main(): number {
        process.stdin.on("data",(buffer) => {
            console.log("Hello World);
        });
        console.log("Test breakpoint");
        return 0;
    }
}
Startup.main();
```

Launch.json
{

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - src/tsconfig.json",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.ts",
        "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vscode's `Debug Console` doesn't support input, so you need a different terminal that does, the integrated one would do just fine. In order to move debug execution from the `Debug Console` to `Terminal` just add a setting to your `launch.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
    ...
}
```

and run debugger again. This way you'll be able to input to command line prompts.

Comment: yeah it worked. thank you. with this configuration, now vs code debugger will use the default system terminal?

Comment: The one configured as default in vscode (usually it's the system default, but can be changed).